# Capacitor discharge of motherboard

Tags: capacitor

After gaming for few hours, I shut down my computer. Immediately when it turned off, I pressed the power button, because I had to turn it on again for a reason. But it turned on after a few seconds, of pressing the switch. It was probably due to capacitors not fully discharged of mobo. So was that fine or might have some risk?

Comment: This was a hard reset so the system will POST, and must execute the firmware loader. Motherboards are too complicated these days to be instant-on. Its not really a cause for concern based on what you have described.

Comment: So is it fine to again press the power button to TURN ON,even when the capacitors of motherboard have not fully electrically discharged?

Comment: Quick answer: Yes. Longer answer: See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no risk. Depending on which caps you're talking about, while the board is operating they are either a) constantly being partially charged and partially discharged many tens of thousands of times a second, or b) staying pretty close to charged all the time. That they might be already partially charged at power-on, even if power-on immediately follows power-off, is not at all a problem.

The power-on delay you experienced was much more likely due to power supply state, not anything happening on the motherboard, anyway. You don't have to worry about the state of the caps in the power supply either, unless you're disassembling it.